# The place of life in nature and time

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

What's the relationship between nature, time and life? Is Nature like a static ball in which Time is a marble rolling in circular defined motion and Life just happens (life is a random indeterminate factor). So how does history happen, by evaporating or being condensed in another form? If time travel is possible? It assumes that life is like a movie and once the scene is played (a day is lived), the script and motion picture is kept in permanence (condensed). Meaning yesterday or the past minute is not only unchangeable but can be retrieved from somewhere. Is all this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy SE! Your question raises many interesting topics. But that is actually a problem, which may cause it to be closed as "to broad". As it stands it could not be answered succinctly and in a reasonable amount of space, so try to edit it so that there is one clear, specific, question. Also make sure you explain how you use certain terms (what exactly do _you_ mean by "Nature"). It can be useful to say what motivated you to ask the question, eg. was it something you read in a book. Finally you could read up on "Asking" in the help center.

Comment: life is a consequence of turbulent entropic flow.

Comment: life/nature is a false dichotomy, life is nature, and time is an intrinsic property of those two things

Comment: Well, my query was technology is increasingly makin the concept of time travel appear possible but how can one revisit the past. What is the state of the past. Will people visit it like a movie but in 9D with special effects? or one can really get into the  moment with their whole body and senses? I focus on life because time and nature are static.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way of scientifically grounding the procession of time is the law of cause and effect.  Causes are causes, and effects are effects... mix that up and you get untenable paradoxes like the Grandfather Paradox.

Physically, my favorite example of the procession of time is the second law of thermodynamics, by which hot things get cooler and warm up their environment, and so nothing is truly reversible.  That's cause-and-effect happening right now, and it can't be stopped.

Comment: The past is gone, friend.  The future is only a twinkle in a person's eye.  The present is, but not anything else.